# How to have a graphical multiboot menu Windows/Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, selection

I have Debian 9.1.0 installed alongside Windows 10. When boot a text menu appears in order to select Windows 10 or Debian.

Looking for another thing I saw in youtube a video where someone had icons of 4 operating systems instead of lines of text to select the OS to run.

How can I do this? if possible, is safe?

PS: Asked by error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106781/how-to-have-a-graphical-multiboot-menu-windows-linux)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Roger Wilco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Wilco)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options - like BURG, GAG, Chameleon, Chimera, etc. but some of them require OSX. based on what you said, [reFind](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is probably the best option for you

It will look like this:

[image: rEFnd boot manager]